# Replace action bar menu through two menu

Tags: android

I want replace current menu of action bar with another when change action bar.

To achieve this I wrote:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu_bar);
```

But it add new menu at the rest of current menu.

What i want is remove current and add the new one.
How can I do that?

Comment: indent code, fix grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer below is correct just has a extra point that will said

You can call invalidateOptionsMenu(), which will cause the system to call onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) again. Inside this method, just check which one of your two menus you should inflate, after calling menu.clear().

Note that invalidateOptionsMenu() has been introduced in API 11 (Honeycomb). If you need to target a lower API level, you can store your Menu object from onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) as an attribute in your Activity, and directly call clear() on it, then inflate the needed menu as you are already doing.

point : at onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) should not call older menu item that lead to Error
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

```
// Error -> menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
menu.clear();
getMenuInflater().inflate(current_menu, menu);
return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `invalidateOptionsMenu()`, which will cause the system to call `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` again. Inside this method, just check which one of your two menus you should inflate, after calling `menu.clear()`.

Note that `invalidateOptionsMenu()` has been introduced in API 11 (Honeycomb). If you need to target a lower API level, you can store your `Menu` object from `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` as an attribute in your `Activity`, and directly call `clear()` on it, then inflate the needed menu as you are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it when changing fragments then:

**(1)** Create a menu file for fragment

**(2)**  `onCreate()` method of Fragment set `setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

**(3)** Override `onCreateOptionsMenu`, where you'll inflate the fragment's menu and attach it to your standard menu.

```
@Override 
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu);
}
```

**(4)** Override `onOptionItemSelected` in your fragment for item handlers.

Check the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar) below for more details..